# Indefinite integrals using Schaum's 16.6

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to integrate a specific function using substitution. The problem refers to Schaum's Mathematical handbook and to a formula 16.6. I understand how to substitute a variable but I do not understand the last part of the 16.6 formula where $\displaystyle\int \frac{F(u)}{f'(x)}\,\mathrm du$. I have substituted $f(x)$ with $t$ and $\mathrm dx$ with $g(t)\,\mathrm dt$ but dividing $F(t)$ with $f'(x)$ is what troubles me.

---UPDATE---

the formula 16.6 is $\int F(f(x))dx =\int F(u)\frac{dx}{du}du =\int \frac{F(u)}{f'(x)}du$, where u=f(x).
I have a function $x^2cos(ln(4x+3)^{1/4})$ which I need to integrate. I've substituted $ln(4x+3)^{1/4}$ with t, x with $\frac{e^{4t}-3}{4}$ and dx with $e^{4t}$dt. What I don't understand is how to implement the formula 16.6 as I don't get the last part of it.

Comment: Could you add some details so that this is readable to someone without Schaum's Mathematical handbook?  What is the specific function that you're trying to integrate?  What is formula 16.6?

Comment: I added the formula to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you have $u = f(x)$, then the differential is $du = f'(x)\; dx.$
If you solve that for $dx$ you get

$$dx = \frac{du}{f'(x)).$$

If you substitute this for $dx$ in the second integral in Formula 16.6, you get the third integral.

I can't tell whether the $1/4$ power in supposed to be inside or outside the $\ln$.  If it's outside, then Maple won't do the integral.  If it's inside, then Maple will do it, but the answer is obscene.

Comment: the answer will be horrible, but I know what to do with it. The problem was the formula 16.6 which I didn't understand